# Convert landscape image to potrait (rotating the image) and save - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

I have an image that is in landscape mode.
This is the image. [image: landscape]

Now I need to convert it to portrait. i.e it should be like this.

[image: potrait]

And the image should be saved in the app directory. (saving part I know.just to complete the question)

How can I do that in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

I use the lib image (https://pub.dev/packages/image) and you can call this code on a button action :

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as ImageLib;


try {
        File contrastFile = File(imagePath);
        ImageLib.Image contrast =
            ImageLib.decodeImage(contrastFile.readAsBytesSync());
        contrast = ImageLib.copyRotate(contrast, -90);
        contrastFile.writeAsBytesSync(ImageLib.encodeJpg(contrast));
        setState(() {
          imageCache.clear();
          imageCache.clearLiveImages();
          reload();
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
```